# How would I get my histogram to output the data vertically?

Tags: python, output, horizontallist, vertical-text

So I have the data to output like this for example
progress 1: *

progress-moduletrailer 4: ****

do_not_progress 6:******

exclude 2: **

But I would want it to show it like this

progress

2:

**

etc

I would appreciate any help with this, very stuck.

```
print("Progress",Progress,  ":", end= " ")
for i in range (Progress):
    print("*", end = " ")
print("\n")

print("Progress_module_trailer",Progress_module_trailer,  ":", end= " ")
for i in range (Progress_module_trailer):
    print("*", end = " ")
print("\n")

print("Do_not_progress_module_trailer",Do_not_progress_module_trailer,  ":", end= " ")
for i in range (Do_not_progress_module_trailer):
    print("*", end = " ")
print("\n")

print("Exclude",Exclude,  ":", end= " ")
for i in range (Exclude):
    print("*", end = " ")
print("\n")

print(Progress+Progress_module_trailer+Do_not_progress_module_trailer+Exclude,"Number of students in total")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the separator argument of the print function and using an `f-string` format as such:

```
print("Progress", f"{Progress}:", sep='\n'))
```

*FYI: The default separator is a single space, changing it to a new line (or 2 new lines if you so wish) can be done through each function call.*

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly a `\n` between progress, the number and the stars should do the trick!
The \n means that a new line is started.
Example:

```py
    print(Hello world)
```

Prints out:

```sh
Hello world
```

but

```py
    print(Hello\nworld)
```

Prints out:

```
Hello
World
```